# Using Spring @EnableRedisHttpSession with master-slave configuration

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-cloud, spring-session

I have a Spring Cloud based application with multiple backend Spring-Boot  servers. The servers are all sharing their session with a single Redis server via @EnableRedisHttpSession.

I now have a requirement for failover support of Redis in production, which means I will have to setup a master-slave configuration (I guess...).

How will I configure Http Session replication via Redis to be aware of the two servers? I could not find any documentation on this. Note that I am not using Spring Data Redis here, just the Spring Session support for Redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Session Redis uses Spring Data Redis to integrate with Redis and so you can use Redis Sentinel (see http://redis.io/topics/sentinel). To give you the full picture:

Redis allows managed (Redis Sentinel) and unmanaged Master-Slave setups. Unmanaged setups provide no failover whereas Sentinel managed setups failover the master node once it's down. Redis Sentinel monitors all master/slave nodes and once a master is not available, a slave will be promoted to a new master.

You can configure Spring Data Redis for Sentinel usage with following properties:

- `spring.redis.sentinel.master`: name of the master node.
- `spring.redis.sentinel.nodes`: Comma delimited list of host:port pairs.

or you provide an own `RedisConnectionFactory` bean. See [Spring Data Redis](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:sentinel) docs for further details.

HTH, Mark

Comment: Thank you very much,  I will look into it. So just to be clear, there are no code changes required? Just update these two properties in aplication.properties or application.yml?

Comment: Correct, no code change required (Note: Redis Sentinel is supported since Spring Data Redis 1.4+)

Comment: I added info to the first question with my issues, would appreciate if you could have a look and perhaps advise on a solution... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I opened the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686670/correct-enableredishttpsession-configuration-with-redis-sentinel