# Correct @EnableRedisHttpSession configuration with Redis Sentinel

Tags: java, redis, spring-session, redis-sentinel

I have a Spring Cloud based application with multiple backend Spring-Boot servers. The servers are all sharing their session with a Redis server via @EnableRedisHttpSession.

I'm trying to configure the application with master-slave configuration and Redis Sentinel. My setup is 1 master, two slaves, and 3 sentinels.

I keep getting issues with the environment. At first, I was getting an error saying that my slave it READONLY. So I had to set all slaves to READWRITE. Then, I still got this error. Turns out that when a slave was promoted to master, the old master was turned into slave, with the default READONLY setting. So I had to set the master to READWRITE as well. These are my commands to boot the redis servers (I know it makes no sense to use the same machine, it's for testing purposes at this stage):

Boot master:

```
redis-server --slave-read-only no --port 6379
```

Boot slaves:

```
redis-server --slaveof 127.0.0.1 6379 --slave-read-only no --port 6380
redis-server --slaveof 127.0.0.1 6379 --slave-read-only no --port 6381
```

application.properties/yml config per spring-boot server participating in the session:

```
#Redis config
spring.redis.sentinel.master: mymaster
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes: localhost:5000,localhost:5001,localhost:5002
```

Redis sentinel config:

```
redis-sentinel sentinel-0.conf
redis-sentinel sentinel-1.conf
redis-sentinel sentinel-2.conf
```

The conf files are:

```
port 5000
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel config-epoch mymaster 6
```

For the other two sentinels it's port 5001 and 5002

Now, as long as everything is normal and there are no issues, everything works fine.

However, once I kill the master redis server, things stop working.
First, I get the following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is     redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

What's worse, when I restart my application, things stop working as well. There are no real errors per say, but the application simply won't work. For example, instead of serving me content, I get a page with just some text (no javascript/css/images). This is usually an indication that it cannot find the session id it needs to use. And this happens even after logout.

I noticed that when I kill the master server, redis sentinel rewrites my config files. For example, after killing the master redis server, the sentinel.conf now appears like this:

```
port 5000
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 6381 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel config-epoch mymaster 6
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/user/odedia/.jenkins/workspace/boot_redis_sentinel_0"
sentinel leader-epoch mymaster 6
sentinel known-slave mymaster 127.0.0.1 6380
sentinel known-slave mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 127.0.0.1 5002 28d5fdf14fcc023045f00b00fcdbd4d4f4554611
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 127.0.0.1 5001 a492f1f0e270fa67c22e057fbd12e981811a79fe
sentinel current-epoch 6
```

And now these settings remain as is even after restarting all servers/redis nodes. I can only get the application working again by manually fixing the config files.

Clearly I can't use this solution at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
2016-02-29 12:11:12.640 ERROR 32389 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.d.r.l.RedisMessageListenerContainer  : Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms
2016-02-29 12:11:16.134 ERROR 32389 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:162) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:251) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:58) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:128) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:91) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:78) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:178) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:153) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:86) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:220) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:233) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:220) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:276) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.updateAccessedSessionAttributes(ServletRequestAttributes.java:255) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes.requestCompleted(AbstractRequestAttributes.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:99) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:12) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:155) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.1.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:82) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1641) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:85) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:48) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158) ~[jedis-2.7.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

Also, here is the output of one of the sentinels log:

````
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.6 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in sentinel mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 5001
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 30337
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

30337:X 29 Feb 12:43:42.898 # Sentinel runid is b2146318c65fb869a5933d6812b41de89cd0131a
30337:X 29 Feb 12:43:42.898 # +monitor master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 quorum 2
30337:X 29 Feb 12:43:45.015 * -dup-sentinel master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 #duplicate of 127.0.0.1:5000 or 719b5af91a18190a4d07059243bb664b95047f0f
30337:X 29 Feb 12:43:45.015 * +sentinel sentinel 127.0.0.1:5000 127.0.0.1 5000 @ mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
30337:X 29 Feb 12:43:45.095 * -dup-sentinel master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 #duplicate of 127.0.0.1:5002 or b375d206c4833c1196911073f63a13f9ee19b5b1
30337:X 29 Feb 12:43:45.095 * +sentinel sentinel 127.0.0.1:5002 127.0.0.1 5002 @ mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
30337:X 29 Feb 12:44:07.928 # +sdown master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
30337:X 29 Feb 12:44:08.502 # +new-epoch 66
30337:X 29 Feb 12:44:08.630 # +vote-for-leader 719b5af91a18190a4d07059243bb664b95047f0f 66
30337:X 29 Feb 12:44:09.094 # +odown master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 #quorum 3/2
30337:X 29 Feb 12:44:09.094 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Mon Feb 29 12:46:08 2016
30337:X 29 Feb 12:46:08.143 # +new-epoch 67
30337:X 29 Feb 12:46:08.144 # +vote-for-leader b375d206c4833c1196911073f63a13f9ee19b5b1 67
30337:X 29 Feb 12:46:08.150 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Mon Feb 29 12:48:08 2016
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.309 # +new-epoch 68
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.310 # +try-failover master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.313 # +vote-for-leader b2146318c65fb869a5933d6812b41de89cd0131a 68
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.318 # 127.0.0.1:5002 voted for b2146318c65fb869a5933d6812b41de89cd0131a 68
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.318 # 127.0.0.1:5000 voted for b2146318c65fb869a5933d6812b41de89cd0131a 68
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.403 # +elected-leader master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.404 # +failover-state-select-slave master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.466 # -failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379
30337:X 29 Feb 12:48:08.525 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Mon Feb 29 12:50:08 2016
````

Here is the log of the Redis master (with the sigterm notification):

````
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.6 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 30316
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.883 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.6
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.883 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.883 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.883 * Connecting to MASTER 127.0.0.1:6380
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.883 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.883 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * Connecting to MASTER 127.0.0.1:6380
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.897 * Full resync from master: 04f525038fe60c44a75fac73285485fa534bf24c:1
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.996 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 18 bytes from master
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.996 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.996 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
30316:S 29 Feb 12:43:43.996 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success
30316:signal-handler (1456742796) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
````

And here is the log of the two Redis slaves:

````
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.6 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6380
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 30319
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.884 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.6
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.884 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.884 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6380
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.891 * Slave 127.0.0.1:6381 asks for synchronization
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.891 * Full resync requested by slave 127.0.0.1:6381
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.891 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.891 * Background saving started by pid 30333
30333:C 29 Feb 12:43:42.901 * DB saved on disk
30333:C 29 Feb 12:43:42.901 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.984 * Background saving terminated with success
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:42.984 * Synchronization with slave 127.0.0.1:6381 succeeded
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * Slave 127.0.0.1:6379 asks for synchronization
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * Full resync requested by slave 127.0.0.1:6379
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:43.896 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
30319:M 29 Feb 12:43:43.897 * Background saving started by pid 30368
30368:C 29 Feb 12:43:43.903 * DB saved on disk
30368:C 29 Feb 12:43:43.903 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
````

Second:

````
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.6 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6381
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 30325
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.889 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.6
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.889 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.889 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6381
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.889 * Connecting to MASTER 127.0.0.1:6380
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.889 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.889 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.890 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.891 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.892 * Full resync from master: 04f525038fe60c44a75fac73285485fa534bf24c:1
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.984 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 18 bytes from master
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.984 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.984 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
30325:S 29 Feb 12:43:42.984 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success
````

Thanks.

Comment: You you add the full stack trace?

Comment: Added. I so far moved to full redis.conf files for each server (master or slave) and skipped the in-line conf settings, I think it was causing issues, mainly because by default all 3 servers were probably writing to the same dump file.
I am now focused on the problem of not getting a connection from pool as described above. When I remove the master, I get the error. When the master is started again - the site is working.

Comment: Added additional logs from redis server master, slaves, sentinel

Comment: Redis Sentinel does not failover according to the logs. Not quite sure why this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It was me being a developer that is not thinking forward enough...

At some point in the very distant past I got exceptions when booting one of the servers (The gateway, which is the important one when it comes to the session management), telling me that it cannot find jedisConnectionFactory bean. So I wrote one, hard-coded, in the main class... pointing to localhost at port 6379 :). No wonder sentinel configuration was ignored.

With that @Bean removed, everything is working perfectly.

The way I found it could be a good point of reference for others. At first, I noticed Spring ignores my entries in application.properties.

So, I wrote my own @Configuration class, with my own sentinelConfig @Bean and my own jedisConnectionFactory @Bean. Spring picked up my sentinelConfig, but totally ignored my jedisConnectionFactory (simple debug identified that issue).

So, I renamed the bean to something like customJedisConnectionFactory, and then I got an error message about having two beans implementing RedisConnectionFactory. From there it was quick to find the other @Bean in my source code.

Thanks.